# Run java application without starting rmiregistry

Tags: java, rmi, rmiregistry

When I'm running a client-server application that use Java RMI, I noticed that it still seems to work even though if I didn't start "rmiregistry" in the command prompt that I was learnt to do. The diffrence in the program I noticed:

```
    try { 
        LocateRegistry.getRegistry(1099).list();
        System.out.println("rmiregistry WAS started before running the application"); } 
    catch (RemoteException e) {
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        System.out.println("rmiregistry WAS NOT started before running the application"); }
```

Anyone with the knowledge could sort out what's happening and how it effect the program?

Comment: As one can do it in code, a command-line start is not needed. In general never use a command line prompt.

Comment: So do you mean that "LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);" starts the rmiregistry if it's not already running?

Comment: Yes, and it fails if the Registry is already running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LocateRegistry.getRegistry(1099).list();
System.out.println("rmiregistry WAS started before running the application"); }
```

That message is misleading. `getRegistry()` doesn't perform any network communication, so the fact that it succeeded isn't a valid indication that the Registry is running. Only *using* the result of `getRegistry()` can tell you that.

You're doing this back to front. You must try the `createRegistry()` call first, and if *that* fails do the `getRegistry() call.`createRegistry()` *will* fail if the Registry is already running, and succeed if it isn't.